# EF query does produces lots of queries

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've got the following datamodel:

```
AuthorizationObject [1 : n] Scopes
```

I want to execute the following select:

```
    var result = await _context.AuthorizationObject
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.RoleId,
            x.DefinitionId,
            Scopes = x.Scopes.Select(s => s.Name).ToList()
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

Since I have to take care about performance, I would like to execute it in one select like (pseudo):

```
select a.RoleId a.DefinitionId s.Name from AuthorizationObject As a
inner join Scope As s ...
```

Unfortunaly it executes something like this:

```
SELECT [x].[RoleId], [x].[DefinitionId], [x].[Id]
FROM [AuthorizationObject] AS [x]

SELECT [s].[ScopeDefinitionId]
FROM [Scope] AS [s]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [s].[AuthorizationObjectId]

SELECT [s].[ScopeDefinitionId]
FROM [Scope] AS [s]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [s].[AuthorizationObjectId]

SELECT [s].[ScopeDefinitionId]
FROM [Scope] AS [s]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [s].[AuthorizationObjectId]

SELECT [s].[ScopeDefinitionId]
FROM [Scope] AS [s]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [s].[AuthorizationObjectId]

SELECT [s].[ScopeDefinitionId]
FROM [Scope] AS [s]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [s].[AuthorizationObjectId]

...
```

**Update:**
Suggested solution by @SamiAl90:
This query

```
    var result = await _context.AuthorizationObject
        .Include(x => x.Scopes)
        .ToListAsync();
```

produces following sql:

```
SELECT [x].[Id], [x].[DefinitionId], [x].[Metadata], [x].[RoleId]
FROM [AuthorizationObject] AS [x]
ORDER BY [x].[Id]

SELECT [x.Scopes].[AuthorizationObjectId], [x.Scopes].[ScopeDefinitionId], [x.Scopes].[ValueString]
FROM [Scope] AS [x.Scopes]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [x0].[Id]
    FROM [AuthorizationObject] AS [x0]
) AS [t] ON [x.Scopes].[AuthorizationObjectId] = [t].[Id]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

```
var result = await context.Set<AuthorizationObject>()
   .AsQueryable()
   .Include(a => a.Scopes)
   .ToListAsync();
```

This will create a query with an INNER JOIN but as a subselect. Still one query though.

Now if you really need a pseudo object you can still create one but IMO it shouldn't be necessary.

**Edit:** Added a [sample project](https://github.com/Birdperson90/ef-include-one-query) that demonstrate that this doesn't cause two queries.

And that is the query that is created

```
SELECT [p.Children].[Id], [p.Children].[ParentId]
FROM [ChildClass] AS [p.Children]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [p0].[Id]
    FROM [ParentClass] AS [p0]
) AS [t] ON [p.Children].[ParentId] = [t].[Id]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]
```

Comment: This is a totally different query. It defeats the purpose of the projection which is: pull less data from the database.

Comment: I would guess, this solution fetches quite a lot of data from the database and also produces at least two queries (which do not look really efficient).

Comment: Yes, it selects everything from a and b but it does it one query. Is the only way you will get it in one query with EF afaik. But selecting everything from a and b, will not really change smth to the performance.

Comment: Added a sample project to prove that this solution is the best performance wise when using EF queries. ADO.NET would be the fastest ofc.